# Rewrite robots.txt based on host with htaccess

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, robots.txt

I'm trying to rewrite a filename based on the server's domain.

This code below is wrong / not working, but illustrates the desired effect.

```
<If "req('Host') != '*.mydevserver.com'">
  RewriteRule "^/robots\.txt$"  "robots-staging.txt"    [R]
</If>
```

Desired effect is this htaccess will point to a different robots.txt depending on if it's on staging (wildcard subdomain) or not.

**Example usage:**

`http://client1.devsite.com/robots.txt` rewritten to
`http://client1.devsite.com/robots-staging.txt`

`http://client2.devsite.com/robots.txt` rewritten to
`http://client2.devsite.com/robots-staging.txt`

`https://client.com/robots.txt` not rewritten
`https://myclient.com/robots.txt`

Answer (score 3):

You can use a more dynamic approach:

```
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ robots/%{HTTP_HOST}.txt [NS]
```

And place your robots.txt files like follows:

- robots/domain.tld.txt
- robots/sub.domain.tld.txt

I came across this solution due to some multi website projects based on TYPO3 CMS and Neos CMS.

Answer (score 2):

I found my own answer. This works as desired.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)?mydevserver(\.com)
    RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ robots-staging.txt [NS]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You could simplify your _CondPattern (`^(.*)?mydevserver(\.com)`) to `mydevserver\.com` (no need for the optional capturing sub patterns and anchors if you are just checking for "mydevserver.com"). You should probably include the `L` flag in case you add more directives.